# Create list of tuples from dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, casting, nested, tuples

I have a simple dictionary:

```
{"keyy":{"key": "value", "cey": "value"}, "kaye":{"key": "value"}}
```

That I want to encode as a "context-aware" tuple:

```
[("keyy","key","value"), ("keyy","cey","value"), ("kaye","key","value")]
```

My attempt with *ValueError: too many values to unpack*:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    mydict={"keyy":{"key": "value", "cey": "value"}, "kaye":{"key", "value"}}
    mytuplelist=[tuple(k,v,val) for (k,v) in [(key,val) for (key,val) in mydict]]
    print mytuplelist
```

**How would I go about creating this list of tuples?**

Comment: `tuple(k,v,val)` should be `(k,v,val)` next

Comment: Yeah, I know, just wanted to explicitly show what I was trying to do.

Comment: thats as explicit as it gets, since `tuple(k,v,val)` is a TypeError :-]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**using list comprehension :**

```
mydict={"keyy":{"key": "value", "cey": "value"}, "kaye":{"key": "value"}}

mytuplelist=[(key,y,mydict[key][y]) for key in mydict for y in mydict[key]]

print (mytuplelist)
```

**output:**

```
[('keyy', 'cey', 'value'), ('keyy', 'key', 'value'), ('kaye', 'key', 'value')]
```

**using Simple For-In loops:**

```
dic={"keyy":{"key": "value", "cey": "value"}, "kaye":{"key": "value"}}
lis=[]
for x in dic:
  for y in dic[x]:
      lis.append((x,y,dic[x][y]))
print(lis)
```

**output:**

```
[('keyy', 'cey', 'value'), ('keyy', 'key', 'value'), ('kaye', 'key', 'value')]
```

Comment: Thanks, this (and the other two) work! :D - To help me decide which to accept, do you think any of you can get it down to one line? :P

Comment: @user1438003 I used list comprehension, it's a one liner.

Comment: I wrote an identical answer with list comprehension. This one is more complete, +1

Answer (score 2):

I like a generator for this:

```
mydict = {"keyy":{"key": "value", "cey": "value"}, "kaye":{"key": "value"}}

def unnest(d):
   for outerkey in d.iterkeys():
       for innerkey, value in d[outerkey].iteritems():
           yield outerkey, innerkey, value

mytuplelist = list(unnest(mydict))
```

Or, you can certainly put it in a list comprehension:

```
mytuplelist = [(outerkey, innerkey, value) for outerkey in mydict.iterkeys() 
               for (innerkey, value) in mydict[outerkey].iteritems()]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following example will create the list of tuples as you indicated:

```
mydict = {"keyy":{"key": "value", "cey": "value"}, "kaye":{"key": "value"}}
tuplelist = []
for outer, dct in mydict.iteritems():
    tuplelist.extend((outer, key, val) for key, val in dct.iteritems())
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix your code:

```
mydict={"keyy":{"key": "value", "cey": "value"}, "kaye":{"key" : "value"}}
mytuplelist = [(outer, inner, val) for outer, d in mydict.iteritems() 
          for inner, val in d.iteritems()]
print mytuplelist
```

See kindall's answer on how to do this the easy way :)

Answer (score 0):

By correcting your typo (missing `:` in the last nested dict, one of possible causes of "too many items to unpack") you can get back your list comprehension:

```
dict1 = {"keyy":{"key": "value", "cey": "value"}, "kaye":{"key": "value"}}

print [(key1, key2, dict1[key1][key2]) for key1 in dict1 for key2 in dict1[key1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a list comprehension

```
>>> D={"keyy":{"key": "value", "cey": "value"}, "kaye":{"key": "value"}}
>>> [(i,)+j for i in D for j in D[i].iteritems()]
[('keyy', 'cey', 'value'), ('keyy', 'key', 'value'), ('kaye', 'key', 'value')]
```